# How to setup remote debugging with Eclipse and PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, remote-debugging

I have been working with a Python program in an Ubuntu 14.04 machine, however, I would like to be able to debug that Python program using Eclipse with the PyDev plugin, but since my Ubuntu machine doesn't have a UI I would like to be able to use my Windows machine, install Eclipse + PyDev on it, and use it to remotely debug the Python program from the Linux machine. Does anybody know how to set that up? I've seen there is something called remote debugger in the PyDev website (http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html), so I'm guessing that is something I may be able to use to do what I want, but I don't get how it works or how to set it up. Can anybody help?

Comment: Have you tried the step by step in the link you provided? Please provide what you have tried and what has failed.

Comment: Well @JonahGraham I could not really tried them since I don't understand them. Specially steps 3 and 4.
I launched Eclipse with PyDev in my windows machine, and started the debug server in the Windows machine. It is supposed to be running in port 5678. Now I guess somehow I need to specify the script that I want to debug that is in the remote linux machine, but I just don't know how.

Comment: What have you tried to add pydevd to your PYTHONPATH. How are you running your script? e.g. python myscript.py or something else?

Comment: e.g. have you done something like import sys;sys.path.append(r'path to pydev/org.python.pydev_4.4.0.201510052309/pysrc')
import pydevd;pydevd.settrace() ? Have you opened pydevd_file_utils.py?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH

Comment: Ohh, so when running my script for remote debuggin (from the linux box) , do I need to modify it first to add the pydevd.settrace() stuff in it and then run it from the command line with python myscript.py? Similar as if I was debugging a script with pdb?If so, how do I bind it with my eclipse in windows then?

Comment: Please read the help to the end, in particular "NOTE 1: the settrace() function can have an optional parameter to specify the host where the remote debugger is listening. E.g.: pydevd.settrace('10.0.0.1')"

Comment: Those instructions are appalling.

Answer (score 11):

Here are the steps I took to be able to debug on Windows a program running on Linux.

1. Open Debug Perspective in Eclipse(Windows), and start PyDev Server
2. On linux run **pip install pydevd**
3. Create a file on both windows and linux with code below
4. Run the created script on Linux
5. When code reaches pydevd.settrace statement it will connect to Eclipse running on Windows, and Eclipse will ask you where it can find the code, point it to where you've stored it on windows.
6. Now you can step through the code, check variable values and etc...

   ```
   import os
   import pydevd
   pydevd.settrace("EclipseIDE_HOSTNAME", port=5678)

   a = 1
   b = 2
   c = a + b

   s = 'hello world'
   print(s)
   ```

Comment: @SAndrew But it'l work nonetheless as long as PyDev is installed (it comes with it, it's just not "seen" by your project). If it bothers you I guess your could 'pip install pydevd' locally or tweak the PYTHONPATH to the where pydevd lives.

Comment: https://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html had the additional info i needed to get the menu entry for starting the PyDev debug server.